# variable font flickers on page load

Tags: css, sass, font-face, webfonts

I have the following problem: I'm using the variable font from the family inter (https://rsms.me/inter/) and implemented it the following way:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Inter var';
  font-weight: 100 900;
  font-display: swap;
  font-style: normal;
  font-named-instance: 'Regular';
  src: url("Inter-roman.var.woff2?v=3.15") format("woff2");
}

html { font-family: 'Inter var', sans-serif; }
```

When styling a font, I only want to change the font-weight, therefore I declare it like this:

```
p { font-variation-settings: 'wght' 200; }
```

The browser renders the font in the correct family and weight, but unfortunately on page load, the font always "flickers" shortly. It seems to me, that the browser first renders the font in the normal font-weight and then re-renders it with my wanted weight. This issue is happening on all fonts I use with the variable font-variation-settings.

The behaviour happens on every page load, also on reloads. You can have a look at the issue during page-reload here:
[image: problem appearing while reloading page]

Thanks for a hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we have found there are many causes for font flickering.

1. The solution for the problem that promted this post was found by the post creator:

   "I have fixed it somehow: I have asked the creator of the font and this was his answer: "Probably because you are using font-display:swap (it intentionally causes "flicker" for requests to fonts that are not cached in the client, which should be rare.) See developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/…" If I change the font-display to block, it does not flicker anymore but there is a longer period of time, where the font doesnt get rendered. I have decided to change the project and work with an standard not variable font. – Mista K."
2. Loading on a server:

   While I am certainly not an expert on this. Loading the file on a server fixes the problem. This is likely due to the style sheet being cached when loaded on a server.
3. Changing font:

   This is not so much a fix, but errors may be caused by the font itself infortunately.
4. Another quick fix:

   Adding a loading screen may be required for a project and thus the font can be loaded within this.

Sorry this is not the most definitive post, this is just what we have found to be solutions over discussing this problem. Feel free to comment on this to add to this or even to tell me I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with the font it's self the best solution I can give is to simply use another font. I would recommend using google fonts

HTML:

```
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans">
    </head>
```

CSS:

```
p {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
```

----------Original Post----------

Why not just simply use `p {font-weight: 200;}` instead, this might solve the problem and would probaly be easier to read (at least from an external persective)

Also try adding your `font-family` to `body` instead of `html` if this doesn't work

Comment: I went with this documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Fonts/Variable_Fonts_Guide

Unfortunately, changing to `font-weight: 200;` or adding `font-family` to `body` doesn't change the problem.

Comment: Sorry to here that it didn't work, I'll look into it a little later on. I'm assuming this happens to all text that uses the font. My only other ideas are that you could be loading a lot of other css file or that the font file it self is somehow 'big'. Try using other fonts in the meantime to check if it is just that one. If all of this doesn't work I would suggest looking into preloading things and adding a loading screen (personally haven't used loading screens so I don't have a clue if that would work)

Comment: Unforunately I can't find a solution to your problem, but it seems to only happen because of this font and not beacause of your code. I would recommend using a different font unless you want to add a loading screen that lets the font flicker before displaying it. Personally I use google fonts so I just add 
 `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans">`
 to the head of my html file and then add it to my css file with `p {font-family: 'Open Sans';}`, this is probably the best solution to your problem. Hope it helps

Comment: @MistaK. Have you fixed the problem? If you havent try testing your site on a server as I have just had a similar problem, offline it had a flickering font but online it works fine, if you're interested here is the [link](https://development.jensonbolton.com/redesign/home/) and I can send you the files if you want to see

Comment: I have fixed it somehow: I have asked the creator of the font and this was his answer: "Probably because you are using font-display:swap (it intentionally causes "flicker" for requests to fonts that are not cached in the client, which should be rare.) See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display"

If I change the font-display to block, it does not flicker anymore but there is a longer period of time, where the font doesnt get rendered.

I have decided to change the project and work with an standard not variable font.

Comment: @MistaK. Good to hear that you fixed the problem. Hope the rest of your project goes well. (I'll add another answer to clarify all the possible solutions for anyone who needs it)